# Finding value in a list of a list?

Tags: python, list

Recently I've been trying to find if a value exists in a list of a list without having to loop through each entry and checking it exists. For example if I have a list like so:

```
items = [{'userAssetId': 1408823681, 'assetId': 116040828, 'name': 'ExampleItem'}, {'userAssetId': 2605640821, 'assetId': 250395631, 'name': 'ExampleItem2'}]
```

If it is possible how would I go about finding the **list or index** that has the assetId of 116040828,  without looping through the main list like so?

```
for item in items:
    if item["assetId"] == 116040828:
        #Found list that includes 116040828
```

Wondering if something like `items.find(116040828)` exists.

Comment: What is wrong with the `for-loop`?

Comment: Wondering if something more optimized, faster and cleaner looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = [{"id": 12345, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 54321, "name": "cba"}]

found = 12345 in map(lambda x: x.get("id"), items)

print("found: ", found)
```

if you want the **item**

```
items = [{"id": 12345, "name": "abc"}, {"id": 54321, "name": "cba"}]

find = 12345
item = next((item for item in items if item["id"] == find), None)

print(item)
```

Comment: Sorry I don't know the best way to word this though I'm not actually looking to check if it exists but actually return the list it is located in.

For example I can find the list 12345 is located in and then from there obtain the name.

Comment: You prob. need to rephrase your `Problem statement` more clear to ask for help then.

Comment: Thanks for your help I keep getting returned "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable". I'm guessing your code is functional and something is wrong with my list? I've updated my list example.

Comment: just update the answer! check it once, now it may fits what you want.

Comment: Finally got it to work! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Using `next`:

```
next((item for item in items if item['id'] == 12345), None)
```

It returns `None` if not found

Answer (score 3):

Like this:

```
   next(filter(lambda x:x['id'] == 12345,items), None)
```